# Why is my GCP Dataflow pipeline unable to create VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I do not see anything in the error message that indicate why it cannot create the VMs.  The error message below was found on the DataFlow web console under the logs "tab".  I couldn't find any more details or any other errors anywhere.

Mar 23, 2016, 1:07:09 PM
(d408c858b9bd6602): Workflow failed. Causes: (7bc822caf77dd216): Unable to create VMs.

We do not have a "default" network, but we are passing --network=ourcustomnetworkname

Cloud SDK version 102.0.0 and the following in my POM:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
<!-- Added to pull in latest build that supports subnetworks -->
  <id>sonatype-staging</id>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
 </repository>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.0, 2.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you also passing a custom `--subnetwork`?

Comment: Specifically, if you're passing a subnetwork, note that the expected format is described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L151) as `zones/ZONE/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK`.

Comment: @Ben Chambers Yes --subnetwork=zones/us-east1-b/subnetworks/edw-dev      I notice in the source code you referenced, that it doesn't specify the format for the network parameter.  Do you know what format the network parameter should be?  Also, my biggest complaint is that I'm not seeing any helpful error message in the logs.  For example, if I'm not passing the correct format, why isn't it saying incorrect format or at least subnetwork not found?

Comment: I think it should work if you specify the network as just the network name (eg., --network=yournetwork) and the subnetwork using `--subnetwork=zones/us-east1-b/subnetworks/edw-dev` you  described.

Regarding the error messages, we're looking into why they aren't showing up and providing more helpful messages.

Comment: @BenChambers we have tried this and it is not working either.  Same error.

Comment: Was the zone (us-east1-b) that you used for the subnetwork the same zone as the GCE instances were running in?

Comment: @BenChambers I have no idea.  How do I tell?  The error says that it couldn't create the VMs.  I don't know where it tried to create them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107371/discussion-between-ben-chambers-and-successhawk).

Comment: In my case It is working with setting subnetwork as e.g. regions/us-central1/subnetworks/dataflow-us-central1 Only.

Answer (score 2):

The network needs to be specified as the complete resource URL, for example `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/latest/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/networks/ourcustomnetworkname`.

You can find this by running `gcloud compute networks describe ourcustomnetworkname` and using the `selfLink` displayed there.

Comment: I get the same error if I add the network param as a self link or if I put in a garbage value.  I also tried to pass a selflink for the subnetwork  param with the same results.  Where did you find this information that the network param's value should be a selflink?  I did not see it in the online docs https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params or the API https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions#getNetwork--